# Falco deployment in namespace

Tags: kubernetes, falco

How do we deploy falco in adifferent namespace as it is deployed in the default namespace? How do we specify on which namespace to install falco charts?

Comment: If the answer below helped you , then please accept the answer by clicking right sign besides the answer. If it does not helped, consider explaining more info why it did not helped.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `-n` flag to specify the custom namespace name and `--create-namespace` flag to create the namespace if its not already present.

```
helm install falco falcosecurity/falco -n falco --create-namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options that allow deploying Falco on Kubernetes non-default namespace (Kubernetes manifest or helm). Using helm with a package from an official document seems the fastest way.

```
# adding repository
helm repo add falcosecurity https://falcosecurity.github.io/charts
helm repo update
# install falco
helm install falco falcosecurity/falco --namespace falco --create-namespace
```

The example above will deploy falco in falco namespace.
To verify the falco deploying status, get pods status & logs:

```
kubectl get pods -n falco -o wide
kubectl logs <falco-pod-name> -n falco
```

If you plan deploy Falco on Kubernetes (EKS), follow the [How to deploy Falco on Kubernetes (EKS)](https://www.galireview.com/blog/how-to-deploy-falco-on-k8s-eks/).
If you want to deploy [Falco on Kubernetes and monitor EKS audit logs](https://dev.to/chrisphan/monitoring-eks-audit-logs-with-falco-security-2f9), follow the Monitoring EKS audit logs with Falco security document.